# How restart function in tabs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

help please understand this problem.
There are tabs, in each of the tabs is iframe, at the bottom of iframe there is a series switch that replaces the src in the iframe, but if you switch to the second tab and click on the series, src is replaced for some reason in the first tab, and not in the second one. How to fix it? Help me please.

**Tabs**

```
    jQuery('ul.tabs').each(function(){

    var $active, $content, $links = jQuery(this).find('a');

    $active = jQuery($links.filter('[href="'+location.hash+'"]')[0] || $links[0]);
    $active.addClass('active');

    $content = $($active[0].hash);

    $links.not($active).each(function () {
        jQuery(this.hash).hide();
    });

    jQuery(this).on('click', 'a', function(e){

        $active.removeClass('active');
        $content.hide();

        $active = jQuery(this);
        $content = jQuery(this.hash);

        $active.addClass('active');
        $content.show('fade');

        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Switch series

```
$('.s-link').on('click', function(){
  $('#series').attr('src', $(this).attr('data-src'));
});
```

**CSS**

```
.tabs {display: flex;position: relative;overflow-x: auto;overflow-y: hidden;height: 48px;
background-color: #f5f5f5;width: 100%;white-space: nowrap;margin: 0px auto;}
.tab_content { background:#fff;padding:10px;width:100% }
.tabs li { display:inline;list-style:none;}
.tabs a {padding: 15px;color:#999;display:inline-block;text-decoration: none; }
.tabs a.active {background-color: #ff4f00;color:#fff }
.series-btn {list-style: none;}
.series-btn li {display:block;border-bottom:1px dashed #eee;padding:0 35px 0 18px;line-height:30px;
white-space:nowrap;cursor:pointer;color:#666;float:left;}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#tab1">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3">3</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tab1" class="tab_content">
    <ul class="tabs">  
        <li><a href="#tab1-1">4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab1-2">5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab1-3">6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab1-4">7</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="tab2" class="tab_content">
    <ul class="tabs">  
        <li><a href="#tab2-1">8</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2-2">9</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2-3">10</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2-4">11</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="tab3" class="tab_content">
    <ul class="tabs">  
        <li><a href="#tab3-1">12</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3-2">13</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3-3">14</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3-4">15</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tab3-1">
      <iframe id="series" class="embed-responsive-item" width="560" height="400" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Uw10XCyFP6E" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
      <ul class="series-btn">
        <li class="s-link" data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/cZBAGbQl1Hc">Episode 1</li>
        <li class="s-link" data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/cZBAGbQl1Hc">Episode 2</li>
        <li class="s-link" data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/cZBAGbQl1Hc">Episode 3</li>
        <li class="s-link" data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/cZBAGbQl1Hc">Episode 4</li>
        <li class="s-link" data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/cZBAGbQl1Hc">Episode 5</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  <div id="tab3-2">
      <iframe id="series" class="embed-responsive-item" width="560" height="400" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Uw10XCyFP6E" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
      <ul class="series-btn">
        <li class="s-link" data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/cZBAGbQl1Hc">Episode 1</li>
        <li class="s-link" data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/cZBAGbQl1Hc">Episode 2</li>
        <li class="s-link" data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/cZBAGbQl1Hc">Episode 3</li>
        <li class="s-link" data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/cZBAGbQl1Hc">Episode 4</li>
        <li class="s-link" data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/cZBAGbQl1Hc">Episode 5</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All frames in your code have the same Id "series". The Id must be unique string. Change them like

```
<iframe id="series1" ...
...
<iframe id="series2" ...
```

Also update the code to switch tabs with different ids.

```
$('.s-link').on('click', function(){
  $('#series' + $(this).attr('data-id')).attr('src', $(this).attr('data-src'));
});

<li class="s-link" data-id="1" data-src="url1" ...
<li class="s-link" data-id="2" data-src="url2" ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you please tell me how to make tabs inside tabs in this code? https://codepen.io/senopsisder/pen/zaEpBV

Comment: Try smth. like css tabs - w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_tabulators.asp

Comment: Or create new post, because actually it is another question :)